# Angular creating a SELECT grouping the options

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project right now that makes use of plenty of information on **selects**.
Is there any way to group this information using native Angular (5/6?) functions?
I tried the ng-select component but did not perform well.

My :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="disbursementType" class="ng-required">Typ wypłaty</label>
  <select id="disbursementType" class="form-control"
          name="disbursementType" required [(ngModel)]="hero.power" #power="ngModel" >
    <option *ngFor="let disbursementTypeOption of disbursementTypeOptions" 
            [value]="disbursementTypeOption.key">{{disbursementTypeOption.title}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And this is my class variable

```
disbursementTypeOptions = [
    {
        "key": 1,
        "title": "Przelew na konto",
        "group": "first",
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "title": "Czek Giro",
        "group": "second",
    },
];
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: When you say "did not perform well", do you mean the app became sluggish or are you saying it did not do what you want? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I mean that it was having some conflicts with the local css, so I rather use a native solution, if available. I'm trying to create a select with groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could slice and dice and array to grouped object inside your component, and then use `optgroup` with `option` tag inside select

**HTML**

```
<select id="disbursementType" class="form-control"
      name="disbursementType" required [(ngModel)]="hero.power" #power="ngModel" >
  <optgroup [attr.label]="group.name" *ngFor="let group of groupedArray">
    <option *ngFor="let disbursementTypeOption of group.values" 
        [value]="disbursementTypeOption.key">
      {{disbursementTypeOption.title}}
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Code**

```
unique: string[];
groupedArray: any[]
formatArray() {
    this.unique = [...new Set(this.disbursementTypeOptions.map(item => item.group))];
    this.groupedArray = unique.map(i => ({
      name: i,
      values: disbursementTypeOptions.filter(d => d.group === i)
    }))
}
```

Comment: I had thought about this but was trying to avoid the extra loop. Apparently I can't run from it... well, I'm gonna test it anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add lodash to use `groupBy`, you can use `rxjs` (since it already comes with angular) like below. Not really useful if you have static data (why not group it in the 1st place), but can be useful with async data.

```
const disbursementTypeOptions: Item[] = [
  {
    'key': 1,
    'title': 'Przelew na konto',
    'group': 'first',
  },
  {
    'key': 2,
    'title': 'Czek Giro',
    'group': 'second',
  },
];

let groups: { group: string, items: Item[] }[];

from(disbursementTypeOptions)
  .pipe(
    groupBy(v => v.group),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray(), map(items => ({ group: group.key, items })))),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(grouped => groups = grouped);
```

Comment: I will definitely try this one also. Thank you!