# Optgroup with ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am getting some data from backend that json looks like this:

```
 {
   "id":1,
   "name":"Colombia La Serrania Omniroast Decaf",
   "manufacturer":{
     "id":16,
     "name":"3fe"
    },
   "manufacturerId":16
```

I care only about 2 fields: coffee name and manufacturer name, so it is coffee.name and coffee.manufacturer.name
What I want to do is to create a select with coffee name options that are grouped by manufacturer name.
Something like that:
[image: list]

Right now I have this:

```
  <select>
    <optgroup *ngFor="let coffee of CoffeeList" label="{{coffee.manufacturer.name}}">
            <option *ngFor="let item of coffee" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

But obviously it is not working. Gettting: **Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'CoffeeName'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.** since coffee isn't iterable. In most of examples I have seen there is usually list inside an object but not in my case. I have no idea how to get it working.

Fetching:

```
  CoffeeList: any[] = [];

 getCoffeesList(){
    this.service.getCoffees().subscribe(data => {
      this.CoffeeList = data;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Aren't you getting an array of objects?

Comment: CoffeeList is an array of objects (updated post to show how it looks like). The problem is (at least from what I understand) "let item of coffee". Angular is expecting coffee to be an array when it is signe object not list.

Comment: Please take a look at this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788014/angular-creating-a-select-grouping-the-options